# How to negating group of characters not single character

Tags: javascript, string, regex-negation

I attempt to not match (negating) group of characters, not single character (i.e [^ha]).

My pattern & string is:

`Str = "habar sahae ha jusk sdgs ha aduh ha hi aha bwahaha aha hahaha huhahu shsha hahihu ha hu ha";
patt = /((?:(?!ha).)+)/gi;`

I want the result is:

`bar sae jusk sdgs aduh hi a bwa a huhu shs hihu hu`

Why the result of my pattern not negated `a` too? The result of my pattern:

`abar saae a a jusk sdgs a aduh a hi aa bwaaa aa huahu shsa ahihu a hu a`

[My pattern, string, and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCFzg.png)

Comment: Would it be possible to shorten your example a little bit to make it clearer what you're trying to achieve? It's a bit hard for me to figure out (although that might just be my problem)

Comment: Are you just trying to remove all instances of the string `ha` ?

Comment: @Evert yes, I just trying to remove all instance of the string `ha`. `(\\s+(?:was|were)\\s+(?:(?!\\w+ing\\b))\\w+)` may I should learn from my that pattern to remove word which ends by ing. When I use `.+` the pattern reject the negate group.